# How to get radio value to different form of submit button in php?

Tags: php, html

I have radio in php, it is included in the form tags which has `post` method. I have a delete button in different `div` and different `form`

So I have this

```
<td style="text-align: center;">
         <input type="radio" name="equipment" value="1" > 
     </td>
```

and then in the other div and form I have this:

```
<div class="col-lg-1">
 <form method="POST">
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" name="delete">Delete</button>
 </form>
 </div>
```

and then at the top of my php file I have this:

```
if(isset($_POST['delete']))
 {
$equipment = $_POST['equipment']; //as you notice this equipment comes from my radio input from the first example above. And the error is here.
echo "<script>";
echo "alert('".$equipment;
echo "'); </script>";
 }
```

So I have this problem for many hours now since yesterday. When I click delete button it shows alert box but after i close it, I get Notice: Undefined Index: equipment in ../etc/phpfile:lineNumber. Basically the error links me to the line number of this code `$equipment = $_POST['equipment'];`

How would I resolve this problem because I want to get the radio value to manipulate mysql using php in later time. For now, I want to output it in alert box.

Comment: shouldnt the radio be inside the same form?

Comment: Put the radio inside the same form

Comment: Should i put the form tag outside the table tag right? so that i can put the delete button after the table tag?

Comment: Okay I got it now but my delete button is floating above the table , however thanks.